Non abelian and countable FC-groups
Let say that a group $G$ is an FC-group if every conjugacy class is finite, that is for every $x \in G$ we have that $\operatorname{C}\ell(x)= \{g x g^{-1} : g \in G\}$ possess a finite cardinality. Clearly, any finite group and any abelian group is an FC-group. Can someone give to me an example if possible of an FC-group that is infinite countable but not abelian?
Thank you.
Edit: Maybe I formulate my question badly. My question is if it is possible that there exist non-abelian infinite countable FC-group or if the only infinite countable FC-groups are abelian. Since every example that cames up to my mind are abelian groups.

Notice that a group with center of finite index is necessarily an FC-group. That should help you in your search.

Your initial question was clear (so, the edit was useless), but you might have searched a little before asking ;-)

@Anne Bauval you are right I had to search a little bit more.

Notice that if there were no-examples of infinite non-abelian FC-groups, this definition would be useless since all finite groups are obviously FC-groups.
As an example, you can take the direct product of an abelian infinite group and a finite non-abelian group. This is clearly still an FC-group, but is not abelian.
